# Remove some part of formatted string from NSDateFormatterLongStyle

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

When working with date formatting in Chinese, for date `Jan, 17, 2015`, if in Chinese locale, with `NSDateFormatterLongStyle`, it will yield:

```
2015年1月17日
```

this is fine, but when I want only the month and year like this:

```
2015年1月
```

there is no such predefined format for this.

If using format template, the template will be `@"YYYY年MM月"`, but this is not localizable for other locales like Japanese.

Is there any way to extract month and year from the long style format for all locales?

Comment: How about extract date components and construct date string yourself? Check docs of  `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalender`. After you get the components, it should be easy to construct a date string with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@年%@月", year, month]`

Comment: @wcd As I've said in my question, string manipulation won't work for other locales that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: how many locales do you need to support? If not many, is a static list of date template string acceptable? I think this technique is used by implementation of `NSDateFormatter` too. All the default date format strings must be saved somewhere in disk and read when app uses date formatter to output date strings.

Comment: @wcd a static list does works, I can't find one however

Comment: man, create one yourself... I think it's easy to do with help of search engine.

Comment: @wcd the problem is that there is no way to verify the list myself.

Comment: you can maintain a list of string constants if not many. Iterating default date format strings of all the locales you need to support may help you to verify the list. A static list is the only way I can think of to solve your problem. Maybe other people has better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playground test:

```
let lc = "zh-cn";
var locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: lc);
var format = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMM", 
    options: 0, locale: locale);
var formatter = NSDateFormatter();
formatter.dateFormat = format;
formatter.locale = locale;
formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate());
```

Production code:

```
var format = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMM", 
    options: 0, locale: nil);
var formatter = NSDateFormatter();
formatter.dateFormat = format;
let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate());
```

Comment: I ran it on my iPad with iOS 8.1.1 and got it correctly from NSLog : `2015-01-17 19:00:55.203 TestLocaleDateSwift[1287:866797] 2015年1月`. I fixed the code to set correct locale to formatter. Please try again.

Comment: this time it worked, I didn't use dateFormatFromTemplate but set format string directly to the formatter instead, this might be the reason that I didn't get the right answer. Also, you don't need to pass local to formatter, using local in dateFormatFromTemplate will do.

Comment: I'm glad it works. The locale stuff is need for the test to be complete by itself (e.g. works even default locale is en-us), I agree it is not for production.